# Why still using richfaces/primefaces with jsf 2.0?

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, richfaces

During an interview, i had this question :

> why still using richfaces or primefaces with jsf 2.0? jsf 2.0 has the ajax capabilities, so what is the advantage of those frameworks vs jsf 2.x ?

Comment: You could have answered : "Why use jQuery if javascript can do it too?"

Comment: i know the answer, i'm just asking to have a discussion about that

Comment: But why this ("-1"), it isn't nice from you : i am newer in jsf, so i have to ask 'some stupid question' (according to you !!!) to learn.

Comment: It's not me, i'll even upvote since i'm curious too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primefaces is a framework on top of JSF-2, and provides components with functionality that would take a big effort to implement in "raw" jsf-2. Look for example at lazy-loading functionality of

[p:dataTable](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/lazy.xhtml)

As with any framework, as long as your application can be adapted to the functionality/components provided, you will gain speed in the development.

The drawbacks is of course you have to learn the framework and if the components available doesn't fit your use case, you have to fallback to "raw"-jsf or perhaps even servlets.

JSF is a framework on top of Servlets technology.